# The record represented by the ID with the Highest aggregate value

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I already have the code to display the highest aggregate value for a ID.

```
select max(fk3_job_role_id),max(sum(no_of_placements))
from fact_accounts
group by fk3_job_role_id
```

the result looks like:

```
[max(fk3_job_role_id)] | [max(sum(no_of_placements))]
-----------------------|-----------------------------
5                      |                    25
```

However, i want to display the job_role_desc instead of fk3_job_role_id represented by the same id.
The table for it looks like:

```
[job_role_id] | [job_role_desc]
--------------------------------
1             |         job1
2             |         job2
3             |         job3
4             |         job4
5             |         job5
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+oracle

Comment: Please edit your query to have sample data and desired results.

Answer (score -2):

```
select job_role_desc,T.total_sum from fact_accounts where job_role_id in (select max(fk3_job_role_id),max(sum(no_of_placements)) as total_sum from fact_accounts group by fk3_job_role_id) T
```

You need to query for the job description by using a subquery. The above query first fetches the data according to the query inside the brackets( also known popularly as a subquery ). The result returned from this query is used to compare with all the other id's in the main table by a simple "in" clause.

> Edit

If you also need the sum of placements you can get it by using a reference to the table created during the execution of the subquery